# Where do this "rect" variable come from?

Tags: swift, swiftui

I copied this period of code to make a clipped shape of rounded corner. But the "rect" variable make me puzzled. It isn't an input variable.How can I use this struct without passing a value or initialize it.

```
import SwiftUI

struct RoundedShape:Shape{
    var corners:UIRectCorner
    func path(in rect:CGRect) -> Path {
        let path=UIBezierPath(roundedRect: rect, byRoundingCorners: corners, cornerRadii: CGSize(width: 80, height: 80))
        return Path(path.cgPath)
        
    }
}
```

⬆️ This is what I got from Internet

```
   Rectangle()
            .clipShape( RoundedShape(corners: [.bottomRight]))
       
    }
```

And I use this struct here and got this

[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/44aOl.png)

Nothing wrong with the result,I just don't understand why this works without any passing or initializing to the "rect".

If you can help me, I appreciate it a lot.

Comment: It is a part of the [`Shape` `protocol`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/shape) SwiftUI knows it is there and calls/initializes it when SwiftUI needs to render the Shape.

Comment: What do you mean by "It isn't an input variable"? If you call *parameters* "input variables", then `rect` is very much an "input variable".

Answer (score 2):

A shape takes all available space in a place where it is created. So `rect` is injected by SwiftUI layout engine and in your case it is all space consumed by parent `Rectangle`:

```
   Rectangle()   // << bounds of this view
            .clipShape( RoundedShape(corners: [.bottomRight]))
```